# Install NetBeans 8.01 in Ubuntu 18.04 - JRE not found

Tags: c++, jdk, netbeans, jre

I have downloaded the netbeans-8.0.1-cpp-linux.sh now I'm trying to install it.

I've authorized the execution.

```
chmod u+x netbeans-8.0.1-cpp-linux.sh
```

Now I'm trying to:

```
sudo ./netbeans-8.0.1-cpp-linux.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/
```

And it keeps saying that JER is not found in the specified place.
I've checked and the JDK is really in the folder /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/

What can I do so solve this problem in order to install NetBeans?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use JDK 11 to install Netbeans 8.0.1.

In order to install Netbeans 8.0.1 you will need to install JDK 8 and use that for the installation.

As an alternative, if the version of Netbeans you use is not important, you could use a later version that does support JDK 11 such as Netbeans 10.